# How can we use mat-datepicker as year picker only Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular6

I want to use mat-datepicker as year picker only. Is there anyway to make it like that?

```
<input name="RegDate" #RegDate="ngModel" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="objCompany.RegDate"
                      class="form-control datepicker" required />
                      <mat-datepicker-toggle class="datepicker-toggler" [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: what is the end value you are looking for ? if it's just the string value of year, I'd recommend to use a basic dropdown with just years. Since if you pick only the year an create a Date object, it will fill the rest of that object with first of January, 00:00:00

Comment: <mat-datepicker #picker (yearSeleceted)="close($event)" startView="multi-year"> have you tried this?

Comment: No it's not working @RohitMittal

Comment: I just want year only @chiril.sarajiu